# Query on entry point annotation in python

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the usage of @main annotation in python.
With the below python program,

```
def cube(x):
    return x * x * x

def run_tests():
    printf("Should be 1:", cube(1))
    printf("Should be 8:", cube(2))
    printf("Should be 27:", cube(3))

@main
def main():
    print("Starting")
    run_tests()
    print("Ending.")
```

I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\MOHET01\Desktop> python.exe -i .\cube.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\cube.py", line 9, in <module>
    @main
NameError: name 'main' is not defined
>>>
```

Function that is imported from ucb is as shown below:

```
def main(fn):
    """Call fn with command line arguments.  Used as a decorator.

    The main decorator marks the function that starts a program. For example,
    interact()
    @main
    def my_run_function():
        # function body

    Use this instead of the typical __name__ == "__main__" predicate.
    """
    if inspect.stack()[1][0].f_locals['__name__'] == '__main__':
        args = sys.argv[1:] # Discard the script name from command line
        print(args)
        print(*args)
        print(fn)
        fn(*args) # Call the main function
    return fn
```

My question:

Despite i define function with intrinsic name main, Why do i see this error?

Comment: Where did you define `@main`? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: What gave you the idea `@main` was a thing in Python? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: @user2357112 Tichodroma  i want to specify an entry point in my program

Comment: What gave you the idea `@main` would do that? Did you see it somewhere?

Comment: @user2357112 am going thru `Section I` in  [link](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa12/labs/lab01/lab01.php) for lab exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@main` decorator is implemented in a file your course provides, but you have not imported it. The page you linked says to use

```
from ucb import main, interact
```

to import the `ucb.py` features in your program.

As for why the error says `name 'main' is not defined`, that's because the function definition doesn't actually finish defining anything until the decorators execute. The reuse of the name `main` for both the decorator and the decorated function is confusing; the `main` in `@main` is a different function from the `main` you're defining in `def main(): ...`. The `main` in `@main` is defined to run the decorated function if the file is run as a script, while the `main` in `def main(): ...` is the function to be run.

---

I would strongly recommend not using anything like this decorator when you don't have to. The standard way to perform the task the decorator performs is to write

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    whatever_function_you_would_have_put_the_decorator_on()
```

or if you want to handle command line arguments like the decorator would,

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    whatever_function_you_would_have_put_the_decorator_on(*sys.argv[1:])
```

The decorator is an attempt to hide the issues of `sys.argv` and `__name__` so you don't have to know about them, but it has a problem. If you try to write something like this:

```
@main
def hello():
    print(hello_string)

hello_string = 'Hi there.'
```

you'll get a `NameError`, because `hello_string` won't be assigned until after the decorator runs. If you continue to write Python beyond this course, you'll find that using `if __name__ == '__main__'` is less bug-prone and more understandable to other programmers than using a decorator for this.

Comment: yes this is the code. `def main(fn):
    """Call fn with command line arguments.  Used as a decorator.

    The main decorator marks the function that starts a program. For example,
    interact()
    @main
    def my_run_function():
        # function body
    
    Use this instead of the typical __name__ == "__main__" predicate.
    """
    if inspect.stack()[1][0].f_locals['__name__'] == '__main__':
        args = sys.argv[1:] # Discard the script name from command line
        fn(*args) # Call the main function
    return fn
` Asper courselogistics, it is too early to understand this code.

Comment: But what for is this function defined? `def main():` as mentioned in query?

Comment: @overexchange: I can't understand your English, but I've expanded the answer in a way that I hope answers your confusion. (I hope you can understand *my* English.)

Comment: Don't worry you understood my Bad English. As am preparing for IELTS, am writing so bad, Otherwise my English was fine before. Fomr my previous comment that i posted, I would like to understand, To what does `fn` point to in `def main(fn):`? Does `def main(fn):` get called when `@main` executes?

Comment: @overexchange: If you pass arguments to your script on the command line (like `python -i your_script_name.py argument`), the `@main` decorator will call the decorated function with the text of the command-line arguments as function arguments (like `main('argument')`).

Comment: As you said 'the `@main` decorator will call the decorated function', I updated the decorated function in the query. I feel the reason why @main is placed at a place where it is, Because decorated function will call the function defined below the decorator `@main`. This magic is all performed by decorated function `def main(fn):`. Am i correct?

Comment: @overexchange: The decorated function is the one you're defining, not the one from `ucb.py`.

Comment: If `def main():` is decorated function then what is `def main(fn):` function from ucb?

Comment: Can i chat with you in Python room?

Comment: @overexchange: Sure. I'm not seeing you in the room; [get in](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).

Comment: From your statement given in the answer: "The decorator is an attempt to hide the issues of sys.argv", Are you saying that, in general decorators are used to read command line arguments?

Comment: @overexchange: No, I'm saying that this particular decorator is used to read command line arguments.

Comment: In my query, Why did the decorator function say `return fn`?Because we are not calling something like `func_var = decorator(fn)` . Decorator has made its purpose by calling `fn(*args)`.

Comment: @overexchange: We are doing something like that, actually. If you try to do anything with the `main` function you defined, you'll get the decorator's return value, since the decorator's return value replaces the function it decorates. `return fn` is necessary to make sure you get the function you defined.

Comment: so every decorator must have `return fn`?

Comment: @overexchange: Most decorators replace the decorated function with something else, often a new function with behavior based on the original.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59705/discussion-between-overexchange-and-user2357112).

Answer (score 2):

I should use this:

```
def main():
    #Do something

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Here use the method that will be the main
    main()
```

I hope this helps

Comment: +1 this is much more conventional than importing some custom decorator

Comment: While this is a better general-purpose way of defining what happens when your file is run as a script than using a decorator (in particular, it doesn't suffer some initialization order problems the decorator has), it doesn't really answer the question. The question is about the decorator and an error involving the decorator, but this answer doesn't mention the decorator at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the function before it is defined. In other words, you need to define the `main` function higher up (in the document) than where you use it as a decorator:

```
   def main():
      pass

   @main
   def somefunction():
      pass
```

The `@main` notation means the main function is being used to "decorate", or modify, another function. There are various articles on python decorators:

- http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/
- http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808
- http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/11/29/improve-your-python-decorators-explained/

Answer (score 0):

You can only use a decorator on a *different* function. Example:

```
def foo(f):
    def inner():
        print("before")
        f()
        print("after")
    return inner

@foo
def bar():
    print("bar")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bar()
```

Output:

```
before
bar
after
```